# How to get Cascading Folder Browser in Dock or Menu?

Tags: dock, folders, menu-bar

Windows offers a cascading folder browser on the menu. It enables very quick drilldown to a buried subfolder.

[image]

How can the be done on a Mac, from the menubar or dock?

This is vaguely similar to the Mac column-browser, but it's ***not a finder window,*** it's a **menu or dock widget.**

Comment: Not sure why you got a down-vote on your question, I thought it was a good question. Which is why I took the time to answer it. At least by up-vote countered it. :)

Comment: @user3439894, perhaps a hater :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Stacks** feature on the **Dock** to accomplish what you're asking.

You can drag and drop the **Macintosh HD** (or any other folder) onto the right side of the **Dock**, to the right of the separator line, to create a Dock item. Then *right-click* it, to bring up its *context menu*, and select **List** under **View content as**. This will give you a cascading menu of the drive.

For more information on **Stacks**, have a look at: [Mac Basics: Stacks are your shortcut in the Dock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201955)

Comment: heh, great answers guys! But, i'm going to mark this one as answer for two reasons: sez to drag HD to right side of dock-- critical step. And was posted 1st. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In the Dock that can easily done by configuring a Dock item (in the example below my System folder) with a right-click:

- View content as: List

[image: Left-click Dock]

Now left-click on the folder in the Dock and navigate to the destination.

Comment: I guess you didn't see what I posted a minute before you, although you did include a picture. :)

Comment: @user3439894 You posted it 5 sec earlier, but at the time of hitting the answer button no other answer was visible! ;-)

Comment: many thx for pic, sorry you did not win answer :(